# PUT Request to REST API using Python

Tags: python, rest, put

For some reason my put request is not working and I am getting syntax errors.  I am new to Python but I have my GET and POST requests working.  Does anyone see anything wrong with this request and any recommendations? I am trying to change the description to "Changed Description"

**PUT**

```
#import requests library for making REST calls
import requests
import json

#specify url
url = 'my URL'

token = "my token"

data = {
        "agentName": "myAgentName",
        "agentId": "20",
        "description": "Changed Description",
        "platform": "Windows"
        }

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, "Content-Type": "application/json", data:data}

#Call REST API
response = requests.put(url, data=data, headers=headers)

#Print Response
print(response.text)
```

Here is the error I am getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 17, in <module>
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, "Content-Type": "application/json", data:data}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: *For some reason my put request is not working and I am getting syntax errors.* Obviously, it's crucial that you copy and paste these errors here, because they will most likely solve the problem *instantly*.

Comment: I agree with you.  I have updated my original post above along with the error.

Comment: You have your `data` in your headers - presumably you just need to delete the data from your headers you already pass it as `data` parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Syntax error in because of `=` sign in your `headers` dictionary:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, "Content-Type": "application/json", data=data}
```

It should be:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, "Content-Type": "application/json", 'data':data}
```

See `data=data` is changed with `'data':data`. Colon and Single Quotes.

And are you sure you will be sending data in your headers? Or you should replace your `payload` with `data` in your `put` request?

Edit:

As you have edited the question and now you are sending data as PUT request's body `requests.put(data=data)` so there is no need of it in headers. Just change your headers to:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, "Content-Type": "application/json"}
```

But as you have set your `Content-Type` header to `application/json` so I think in your PUT request you should do

```
response = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

that is send your data as json.

Comment: I have made the changes to my original post but still receiving an error.  Any additional thoughts?

Comment: @Tim you are still missing single quotes around your `'data':data`. `data` is a dict which can not be a key for another dict.

Comment: you are correct.  This is what I needed to do.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you try to assign `data` to the `data` element in your dictionary:

```
headers = { ..., data:data }
```

That can't work because you can't use a dictionary as a key in a dictionary (technically, because it's not hashable).

You probably wanted to do

```
headers = { ..., "data":data }
```

Comment: Unfortunately Marcus the problem was not with quotes missing around data but instead data should not have been in my header to begin with.

Comment: @Tim I took the code directly from your error message, so it was definitely there!

Comment: Always make sure that the code you post is exactly the code with which you have problems